# CodePushHash not found working with Code Push

Tags: android, react-native, code-push, react-native-code-push

So I'm trying to deploy my React Native app using the App Center and integrate Code Push.
I installed the App Center SDK and workds properly but the problem comes when I add the Code Push plugin. It compiles the project nicely and does the sync too, but when I try to install it on my device the build falis saying:
 "Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1"
and "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/balistic/Documents/sharryup/android/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug/CodePushHash'"

I'm using React Native 0.56.

Comment: If I run with gradle's install command then the build is successful and does install 
 perfectly on the device, otherwise If I run android app configuration then I face the same issue

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: The fact is that  my project team decided to implement this feature once the whole project is up and running. Actually codepush requires a really good management of the project between different people, otherwise it could be even perjudicating.
Probably I was missing some part of the configuration but I did not continue working with it. Sorry.

Comment: Same issue here any update on this?

After upgrading to ReactNative 0.56.1

Answer (score -2):

```
There is a workaround for this:
In {project_dir}/node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/codepush.gradle (~86-90) just add this three lines:

generateBundledResourcesHash = tasks.create(
        name: "generateBundledResourcesHash${targetName}",
        type: Exec) {
+doFirst {
+jsBundleDir.mkdirs()
+}
    commandLine (*nodeExecutableAndArgs, "${nodeModulesPath}/react-native-code-push/scripts/generateBundledResourcesHash.js", resourcesDir, jsBundleFile, jsBundleDir, resourcesMapTempFileName)
}
```

Comment: Bad idea! You shouldn't be hacking your dependencies.